# How to read a config value in tmux?

Tags: tmux

I'm using a tmux plugin that sets `status-right` to some long formatting string. I'd like to prepend something to that string, just like I can do in bash (i.e. `export PATH="foo:$PATH"`). Should be fairly trivial, but googleing around has not led me to a solution. Am I missing something obvious here, or is this really not possible?

Answer (score 1):

You can get it in a script with: tmux display -p '#{status-right}'

Comment: Thanks, but can you give me an example how I would set it in tmux.conf? I have tried `set -g status-right "foo $(tmux display -p '#{status-right}')"` after loading the plugin and it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Setting `status-right` to a value that includes `status-right` seems to be a bit tricky, as you may end up in some sort of recursion. The only thing that worked for me was to use (in `~/.tmux.conf`)

```
run-shell "tmux set-option -g status-right 'foo #{status-right}'"
```

This works because tmux replaces any `#{}` variables within the string argument to `run-shell` before executing it, so you actually call tmux with the final string already calculated.